# Calculate velocity after certain displacement

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Given is a function $a(t)$ for the acceleration. Starting from an initial velocity $v_0$ I want to calculate the velocity $v_1$ after a certain displacement $s$.

Is this calculation possible since there is no time involved although $a$ is a function of time?

What I actually know:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t} = \int a(t) \:\mathrm{d}t$$

But does this help me since it's the derivation/integration over time.

Comment: First, find $s^{-1}$. Then, for any given displacement $d$, $s^{-1}(d)$ is the time, and so $v(s^{-1}(d)) = v_0 + \int_0^{s^{-1}(d)} a(\tau) d\tau$. (I assume that $s$ is invertible of course.)

Comment: @aflous I don't think your expression makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, if the velocity is always positive.

If that is the case, then the function $s(t)$ is invertible, and you are at the position $s$ only at the time $t(s)$. Moreover, the derivative of $t(s)$ is:
$$
\frac{dt}{ds} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ds}{dt}}.
$$

Therefore:
$$
a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}\,\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dv(x)}{dx}\, v(t),
$$

for some function $v(x)$ (that is exactly what you want to find), such that $v(x(t))= v(t)$.

In Leibniz notation:
$$
a\cdot dx = v\cdot dv,
$$

which means:
$$
\int_{x_0}^x a(x)\cdot dx =  \int_{v_0}^v v\cdot dv = \frac{1}{2}v^2 - \frac{1}{2}v_0^2.
$$

So:
$$
v^2 = v_0^2 + 2\int_{x_0}^x a\cdot dx,
$$

and to get $v$ just take the square root.

For example, if $a$ is constant, you get the well known relation:
$$
v^2 = v_0^2 + 2a\cdot \Delta x.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question to this: How to transform some given $a(t)$ to an $a(x)$? For my case a is not constant it's some exponential over time,

Comment: The simplest method is: integrate twice to find $x(t)$. Then take the inverse function $t(x)$, and plug it in $a(t)$.

Comment: By the way, if it is exponential, it means that $a=-kv$ for some $k$. If you plug it in $a\,dx=v\,dv$ and integrate directly, you get $v=v_0-k(x-x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments for a given function of displacement with time $t$ can be find as a inverse function of displacement.
$$s=f(t) \implies t=f^{-1}(s)$$  .
Now You can use the expression
$$v_2=v_1+\int_{t_1}^{{t_2}} adt$$$$v_2=v_1+\int_{f^{-1}(s_1)}^{f^{-1}{(s_2)}} adt$$